# After echo, why does cmd not open to the desired location?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

In this code, cmd does not open to the desired location:

```
::fileinfo: "javaday.bat" by Wolfpack08 4/2014
@echo off
::"Good morning" appears in CMD.
echo "Good morning."

::Important directories are opened.
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "c:\Users\Wolfpack08\java_apps"
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "c:\utils"

::Open up the programs I use.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Anki\anki.exe"

::Open up cmd prompt to the desired location.
::THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE.
cmd /k start "" /d"c:\Users\wolfpack08\java_apps"
```

Now, in this code (below), cmd does open to the desired location:

```
::fileinfo: "javaday.bat" by Wolfpack08 4/2014
@echo off

::Open up cmd prompt to the desired location.
::THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE.
cmd /k start "" /d"c:\Users\wolfpack08\java_apps"

::"Good morning" appears in CMD.
echo "Good morning."

::Important directories are opened.
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "c:\Users\Wolfpack08\java_apps"
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "c:\utils"

::Open up the programs I use.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Anki\anki.exe"
```

### Expected behavior

When I run javaday.bat, I expect an instance of cmd to open to c:\Users\wolfpack08\java_apps.

### Actual behavior

"Good morning" remains in cmd.  There's no cursor (I can't type).

### What I've tried

Tried messing with the code and remarking lines.

### Additional info

When cmd is already open, it succeeds.  For example, on second execution this succeeds.  So, it's kind of an intermittent issue.

Comment: This is pure speculation, but try doing `echo "Good morning!"`

Comment: @merlin2011 I'm already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

This will open a cmd prompt in a folder:

```
@echo off
start "" /d"c:\Users" cmd /k
```

Answer (score 0):

The /c switch executes the command and then exits.  Try the /k switch, which executes the command and stays open.  Something like:

```
start cmd /k "cd c:\users\wolfpack08\java_apps"
```

Comment: The problem persists.

Comment: If you put "Good morning!" (no quotes) and you only see "Good morning" (no quotes) on the screen, then you must escape the ! character with ^^! or surround "Good morning!" in quotes as merlin2011 suggested.  I didn't notice this because I thought that all of the lines after the echo had executed, other than opening the cmd instance.  If the execution is stopping there, try removing the whole echo line for a moment and see if everything else works properly.

Comment: Doesn't work.  The quotes and escaping character don't resolve the actual issue.